# Matlab Polarplot() and surface color

Tags: matlab, plot, colormap, polar-coordinates

I am a bit struggling with my polar plot. I am playing with strikes and dips, and for each pair of those, an "intensity". I'd like to plot this surface/contourf/whatever function on my polarplot. I cannot find the handle to do so. Dpp2 contains the intensity value for a given theta and rho/ strike and dip.

```
xTmp = (0:4:360);
yTmp = (0:22.5:90);

[strike,dip]= meshgrid(deg2rad(xTmp),deg2rad(yTmp));

dip2 = rad2deg(dip);
strike2 =rad2deg(strike);

figure('name', 'COLD');
polarplot([0 360],[0 90]);

s = surf(strike2, dip2, DPp2);

polarplot(s);
colormap
```

I've tried something like that, which obviously doesn't work.

cheers,
Flo

Comment: _Undefined function or variable_ `DPp2`. We cannot run your sample code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way of creating a surface plot directly in a polarplot.

One workaround is to manually create your polar axis plot. You can find an example [here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95796-how-do-i-create-a-contour-plot-in-polar-coordinates).

Another workaround would be to use 
`polarscatter` to create a scatter plot (which looks simmilar in case you have a tight grid) Have a look at [this](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polarscatter.html?s_tid=doc_ta).

Because you mentioned the handle: In case you want a handle to the axes have a look at `polaraxes` from [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polaraxes.html?s_tid=doc_ta).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I'll try the scatter solution and come back to you

Answer (score 0):

The polar scatter wasn't working, so I tried another function, which seems to work according to this page: https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95796-how-do-i-create-a-contour-plot-in-polar-coordinates

I am note quite there yet, the contour map isn't "wrapped" around my polar plot, but so far it's compiling. If anyone has an idea  on how to superimpose the contour map onto the polar plot ?

```
dip2 = rad2deg(dip);
strike2 =rad2deg(strike);


h = polar([0 360],[0 90]);
hold on;
contourf(strike2,dip2,DPp2);
% Hide the POLAR function data and leave annotations
set(h,'Visible','off')
% Turn off axes and set square aspect ratio
axis off
axis image
```